# Linux Serial Read throws Error

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I'm attempting to read from my serial port using the following C code. I can successfully write to a listening computer (yay!) but the read throws Error (Code 11 - Resource temporarily unavailable). I have also noticed my messages/dmesg logs don't have any information regarding faults,etc. So that's good.

```
//A bunch of INCLUDES exist here....the the code

int fd=0;
int status=0;
int running=1;
char buffer[100];
char message[7];

void main(){
    fd = 1;

    fd=open("/dev/ttyM0",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

    if(fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttys0");
    }
    else
    {
        while(running<20)
        {
            sprintf(message,"Test%d\r",running);
            status=write(fd,message,6);

            if(status<0)
            {
                printf("Error Writing. Status=%d\n %s\n",errno, strerror(errno));
            }
            status=read(fd,buffer,8);  //This throws an error(11). My connected device is writing "Testing/r"

            if(status<0)
            {
                printf("Error Reading. Status=%d \n%s\n",errno, strerror(errno));
                //close(fd);
                running=running+1;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%s\n\r",buffer);
            }
            sleep(2);
        }
        close(fd);
    }

} //END MAIN
```

These are my serial settings for my port. I'm attempting to read/write at 9600 8bit, No parity, 1 stop bit. I think my settings are correct.

```
sudo stty -a -F /dev/ttyM0 
speed 9600 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany
-imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613916/linux-serial-port-read-returning-eagain

Comment: yea, I read this post before and I agree that data isn't going to always be available when using the O_NDELAY flag but I've handled this by running my code a loop. The example you point to only calls read once.

Comment: @Craig -- Read the **man** page for **open()**: O_NDELAY is the same as O_NONBLOCK.  So you have opened the serial port for *nonblocked* I/O.  You have to anticipate and properly handle the EAGAIN return code.  If you don't know how to handle EAGAIN, then the simple solution is to perform blocked I/O.  IMO if all you're going to do is loop waiting for data to read, then you should be using a blocked read.

Comment: **read()** does not store a null-terminated text string (unless that's what is actually transmitted and received), so the subsequent **printf()** will probably output spurious characters.

Comment: Thx sawdust. Ok, I edited my post to show what I'm doing now (I hope that's ok for this community). Interestingly enough the data i'm WRITING (from my test machine to my linux box) is being echoed back from my linux box. When I turn off echo (using stty cmd it stops echoing) so I think this means my device IS receiving my data but still the read command isn't working. With O_NDELAY gone the program just sits there waiting for input (this is what I expected but not the desired result). Give me a little time to read through the man on my functions. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Looks like termios is setup for canonical input (based on the **icanon** in the **stty** output).  Verify that your remote device is actually sending a CR or LF control character to terminate the line.  Your comment in the code indicates that it is not (i.e. "/r" is not a carriage return).

Comment: That was it. Thank you. I had carriage return (eventhough the comment was wrong) but didn't it was showing up as \\r. Ug, soo simple. Thanks for all the help. Sawdust, if you'd like to enter that as an "answer" I'll mark it so you  get the credit. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With O_NDELAY gone the program just sits there waiting for input

Looks like *termios* is setup for canonical input (based on the **icanon** in the **stty** output). In canonical (aka cooked) mode, the characters received from the serial port are processed before being made available to the user program using **read()**.

Per the Linux man page:

> In canonical mode:
>
> - Input is made available line by line.  An input line is available
>     when one of the line delimiters is typed (NL, EOL, EOL2; or EOF at
>     the start of line).  Except in the case of EOF, the line delimiter
>     is included in the buffer returned by read(2).

Your *termios* also has **icrnl** set, which means that a carriage return is translated to newline on input (unless **igncr** is set, which is not since it has a preceding hyphen).  Both **eol** and **eol2** are undefined (which are the default values).

So for your setup, an end-of-line is defined as a newline or a carriage return (or cntl-D at the start of the line).  Verify that your remote device is actually sending a CR or LF control character to terminate the line. Your comment in the code indicates that it is not (i.e. "/r" is not a carriage return).

---

To properly use the text returned by **read()** as a string, set the request for one less than the allocated buffer size (to ensure room for appending a null terminator).   Then after a good return, use the returned byte count as the index to store the string terminator.

```
        status = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);  
        if (status < 0) {
            /* handle error condition */
        } else {
            buffer[status] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n\r", buffer);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a buffer overflow here:

```
sprintf(message,"Test%d\r",running);
```

since `message` is declared as:

```
char message[6];
```

`message` needs to be at least 7 characters in size if it's going to hold a 6 character string, due to the need for a `'\0'` terminator.

There may well be other problems too, but you should fix this and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Good catch. I've updated this to char message[7] and ran the software again. My reads are still throwing the same error. Thanks for the code review!

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `O_NDELAY` option in your `open` call. This make the file descriptor **non-blocking**. This means that if you do a `read` and there's no data available, the `read` call will return `EAGAIN` which is the error you're seeing.

For the moment, you can remove the `O_NDELAY` from `open`. In the future, you should probably make it non-blocking again and use either `select` or `poll` to determine when you can read.

Comment: @BenVoigt - without using `poll` or `select`, you would have to either sleep between tries or use a hard loop to retry reads. It'll work, but it's far from ideal.