# Reading on serial port returns what i just wrote

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

I just started a project where i'm struggling since days now about serial ports. I wrote a static library that can handle all the serial routine and give an interface with "readLine()" and "writeLine()" functions.
Everything works flawlessly on the write and read (which are threaded by the way) except if the slave does not anwser after he gets the data, then, the data is sent back to me, and i read it.

I open my fd with O_NDELAY and configure my read system call as Non blocking with fcntl.

here are the two threaded loops that work perfectly beside that.

```
void *Serial_Port::readLoop(void *param)
{
  Serial_Port *sp = static_cast<Serial_Port*>(param);
  std::string *line = NULL;
  char buffer[128];

  while (1)
    {
      line = new std::string();
      while ((line->find("\r\n")) == std::string::npos)
        {
          usleep(100);
          bzero(buffer, 128);
          pthread_mutex_lock(sp->getRLock());
          if (read(sp->getDescriptor(), buffer, 127) > 0)
            *line += buffer;
          pthread_mutex_unlock(sp->getRLock());
        }
      pthread_mutex_lock(sp->getRLock());
      sp->getRStack()->push(line->substr(0, line->find("\r\n")));
      pthread_mutex_unlock(sp->getRLock());
      delete (line);
    }
  return (param);
}

void *Serial_Port::writeLoop(void *param)
{
  Serial_Port *sp = static_cast<Serial_Port*>(param);
  std::string *line;

  while (1)
    {
      line = NULL;
      pthread_mutex_lock(sp->getWLock());
      if (!sp->getWStack()->empty())
        {
          line = new std::string(sp->getWStack()->front());
          sp->getWStack()->pop();
        }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(sp->getWLock());
      if (line != NULL)
        {
          pthread_mutex_lock(sp->getWLock());
          write(sp->getDescriptor(), line->c_str(), line->length());
          // fsync(sp->getDescriptor());                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
          pthread_mutex_unlock(sp->getWLock());
        }
      usleep(100);
    }
  return (param);
}
```

I tried to flush the file descriptor, but i can't manage to receive any data after doing that. How can I get rid of that duplicate, needless data?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you disabled local echo?  *"configure my read system call as Non blocking"* -- Probably a bad idea, since you seem to be just wasting more CPU cycles delaying and polling.  To read lines from a terminal, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586137/stop-on-newline-when-using-read/36588517#36588517

Comment: I was forced to put read in non blocking mode, as it wouldnt release the mutex as long as there was nothing to read.. I have not thinked about any other alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple tests and behavior analysis, I discovered it was the "Pulsar3" (the device i was using on serial) that kept giving me back what i sent as "Acknowledge". Nice to know!

Comment: This is very common in serial devices that are meant to be connected to a CRT. The CRT does not display what you enter at the keyboard, by convention, so it's the responsibility of the remote system to echo it back at you so you can see it.