# serial c to read in linux with issues

Tags: c, linux, arduino, serial-port

I am try to use Odroid(single-computer board) reads serial in C to get data from arduino board with usb cable. which is publishing sensor data is like **189**. The baudrate is 115200.

**The mmain code about read useage :**

```
#include <stdio.h> /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h> /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h> /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h> /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h> /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include "share.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwrite-strings"

/*
 * @brief Open serial port with the given device name
 *
 * @return The file descriptor on success or -1 on error.
 */
int open_port(char *port_device)
{
    int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */

    fd = open(port_device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/Servo_LIDAR ");
    }
    else
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

    return (fd);
}

int main()
{

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    struct termios options;
    int fd=-1;
    char *u_port = "/dev/Servo_LIDAR";
    fd=open_port(u_port);
    if(fd==-1)
    {
       printf("port not open");
       return -1;
    }

    tcgetattr(fd, &options);
    cfsetispeed(&options, B115200);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B115200);

    //Enable the receiver and set local mode...
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Mask the character size bits */
    options.c_cflag |= CS8; /* Select 8 data bits */

    //No parity
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;

    //Set the new options for the port...
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);


    printf("Reading...\n"); 

   while(true) 
  {


    while(1)
    {       
        //sleep(0.5);
        char buff[1024]={0};
        char buf[1]={0};
        while(1) {  
           ssize_t res=read(fd, buf, 1);

           if(res==0) continue;  
           buf[res]=0;  

           strcat(buff,buf);
           if (buf[0] == '\n')  break; 
      }  
      printf("%s\n", buff); 
      usleep(70000);
    break;
    }
 }

    close(fd);


}
```

I got date like:

> 187
>
> 187187187
>
> 188
>
> 188188
>
> 188188188
>
> 188
>
> 1888
>
> 188
>
> 18188
>
> 188
>
> 186187
>
> 187
>
> 187

It should be like 3 bytes data each time,but I got issues like this. Any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I tried debug with GDB, no crash happened. But got same data. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Debugging is not only for catching crashes, but also for stepping though code, line by line, while watching variables and their values. This way you could step through the loop reading data, and see what happens and what it does. If it works as it should (and it looks like it would) then the error is somewhere else. By the way, if there's an error reading (when `read` return `-1`) you might want to print it out. The code as shown propagates the error upward, but you don't seem to actually do anything when there's an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary bug involves the statements:

```
    char buf[1]={0};
...  
       ssize_t res=read(fd, buf, 1);
...
       buf[res]=0;
```

The array **buf[]** is declared to be only *one* element long, i.e. **buf[0]** is the only element of the array.
The **read()** syscall will have a return value of 1 on success, since that is the specified count.
Then you try to null terminate the received text by writing to **buf[1]**, but that is an element that has not been allocated.
The array **buf[]** needs to be at least 2 elements long.

The symptoms of this bug will vary according to the compiler and host system.  On an x86 laptop using gcc 4.8.4, your original program produces no output at all.

For the preferred method of terminating the buffer data see [Linux Serial Read throws Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526576/linux-serial-read-throws-error/32572202#32572202)

---

**Code Review**

1. All syscalls, including **tc[gs]etattr()** and **read()**, should be checked for error return codes, especially when your program does not behave as you expect.
2. Your **termios** configuration is incomplete.  Your program will execute with whatever previous canonical or non-canonical mode that was configured.  That can produce unexpected results.
3. Reading just one character at a time (nested in several while loops) is inefficient.  A canonical read could return a line per each syscall.  Study ["Two Styles of Input: Canonical or Not"](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC233)
4. Program delays such as `usleep(70000)` are superfluous.  The file/device has been opened for blocking reads, so the **read()** will not return until data is available.

Comment: thanks for your help. It's really give a comprehensive understanding about serial. I will check one by one as you suggest

Comment: Forgot to mention that your program seems to expect the default termios settings.  I.E. executing the command `stty -F /dev/ttyXXX sane` got it "working".

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I would try. First is to adjust the sleep after read returns 0 bytes. If Serial-port is not buffered/interrupt driven, 10ms is very close the time one bytes takes to be received (which is 11.52 with the current baudrate).

Second issue might be on the output end. Have you considered that the problem might be there? try to only print back every 10th reading, causing less traffic on the output end.